# AWS S3 LS --include: Unknown options

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm on the newest AWS CLI version - 2.7.24

Trying to list all the files from all the folders I have (with a certain extension) on this path:

s3://myfiles/folders/

"folders" have this structure:

```
folder1
 - item
 - item
folder2
 - item
 - item
folder3
 - item
 - item
```

My aws cli command is:

**aws s3 ls --recursive s3://myfiles/folders/** -> Which works fine. But when I add --include, it doesn't work. Error: unknown options

Example:
aws s3 ls --recursive --exclude * --include "*.txt" s3://myfiles/folders/

**Error:** Unknown options: --exclude, , --include,*.txt

I did pip install -U awscli

I tried a lot of internet and stackoverflow stuff but nothing worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at what `aws s3 ls help` tells you

Comment: @Paolo it doesn't even have any options about --include or --exclude. Is it possible that it's been evicted from aws s3 ls?

Comment: Those options are valid for `aws s3 cp`, not for `aws s3 ls`

Comment: I think your `*` and maybe `"*.txt"` are being expanded by the shell before being passed into the AWS cli command. You can check this by running `echo aws s3 ls --recursive --exclude * --include "*.txt" s3://myfiles/folders/` to see what is getting expanded. At a minimum you need to wrap the `*` in quotes.

Comment: @MarkB as a result I get this `aws s3 ls --recursive --exclude * --include *.txt s3://myfiles/folders/`

And yes, I wrapped `*` with quotes

Comment: `aws s3 ls` never supported `--include` or `--exclude`.  There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4832) for such support, but as it is now, you'll need to use some external program to accomplish this goal.

Comment: @AnonCoward any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: You can use something like 'grep', see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily build the desired functionality by piping the result of the aws cli command to grep or similar.

---

In Bash:

Here's an example which mirrors the "include" functionality:

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://bucket --recursive | grep ".*.txt.*"
```

Here's an example which mirrors the "exclude" functionality:

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://bucket --recursive | grep -v ".*.txt.*"
```

---

In Powershell:

Here's an example which mirrors the "include" functionality:

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://bucket --recursive | Select-String ".*.txt.*"
```

Here's an example which mirrors the "exclude" functionality:

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://bucket --recursive | Select-String ".*.txt.*" -NotMatch
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no such option as

```
aws s3 ls --include
```

or

```
aws s3 ls --exclude
```

There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4832) for that, but no solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can do expansions with s3 `ls` if you want to match the beginning of the path...

If I want to find all paths that start with a capital "C" inside a certain directory I can do this:

```
aws s3 ls my-bucket/my-folder/C
```

And it'll match all folders that start with "C" inside `my-bucket/my-folder/`.